# Im using ReactNative and MobX. How to trigger component render when returning to it via GoBack()

Tags: react-native, mobx

I need to make a component re-render when returning to it. That is, when calling GoBack() in navigation. The data becomes outdated very quickly and when returning to the previous component, it is very possible that this data is already outdated. The presence of buttons and other components depends on the data. What is needed is a re-rendering of the entire component.